# Is a line bivector the same thing as a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

In the abstract of this [article](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Efaris/vector5.pdf), the author said the following:

> An element of this vector space will be called a line bivector.

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space),

> ..., a vector space (also called a linear space) is a set of objects
> called vectors, ...

So, if a line bivector is an element of a vector space, then a line bivector must be a vector since all the elements of a vector space are vectors. Am I correct?

**PS:** I'm a complete amateur in linear algebra.

Comment: Not sure what your point is.  The author of that article is introducing a definition specific to its context.  This is certainly not a universally accepted bit of terminology.

Comment: Look up Geometric Algebra.

Comment: Found the following later in the article, "Sliding vectors form part of a larger vector space. An element of this larger
space will be called a line bivector or a screw. We shall see that the term “line
bivector” is geometrically natural. Other terms like “screw” and “wrench” may
be appropriate in physical applications. The precise definition of line bivector
is given later on, but here is a brief preview. A line bivector may be represented
(not uniquely) in the form

$$M = P ∧ u + α,$$

where $α$ is a bivector built over the $n$ dimensional vector space $V$."

Comment: [I am sure you'll find this video helpful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=60z_hpEAtD8). Also see the other videos on the Channel. He gives a brief course on linear algebra with the goal of building up to GA ideas. You can also check out Geometric Algebra book by Alan Macdonald. It builds LA into GA. However it maybe beyond depth that you seek for at the moment.

Comment: @Buraian Thank you so much, sir!

Comment: Apparently, the subset of a vector space is not necessarily a vector space. Later in the article, "The collection of all sliding vectors $P ∧ u$ where $P$ and **u** both vary is
not a vector space; it is a subset of the vector space of line bivectors of dimension
$2n − 1$." See [quora](https://qr.ae/pGLB7D).

Comment: Later in the article "It also gives a way to describe the situation in dimension n = 3,
where a bivector is often represented by a pseudovector."

Comment: Yes, a subset of a vector space is not necessarily a vector space. I recommend that you look at some basic linear algebra first --- the MIT opencourseware lectures publicly available on YouTube, by Gilbert Strang, are a good resource. The reason is that vector spaces must be closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication, while arbitrary subsets of a vector space need not be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are technically correct that bivectors are also vectors in the sense that they live in a vector space. The issue here is that there is a conflicting use of terminology: in some contexts (particularly differential geometry and in physics), the term "vector" only refers to members of a particular type of vector space, while "bivector" then denotes something different, related to the first fixed vector space.

For example, in these contexts, "vector" might specifically refer to an element of $\mathbb R^n$, i.e. an $n$-dimensional Euclidean vector, while then bivector refers to a linear combination of terms of the form $e_i\wedge e_j$ where $e_i$ are basis vectors for $\mathbb R^n$ and $\wedge$ denotes the exterior product.

An analogy: the term "scalar" is typically used when we already have a vector space $V$ fixed over a particular field $K$, where elements of this base field $K$ are then called scalars. This is a relative notion to the vector space $V$. So, for example, it is true that $\mathbb R$ is a vector space over itself, so elements of $\mathbb R$ can be called vectors too --- but in some contexts, such as in physics, you normally think of real numbers as scalars. Similar is true for "bivector", this is also used when the first vector space $V$ is already fixed in mind.